# OpenGL Graphics Artifacts

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm having some graphics artifacts in OpenGL (I'm using LWJGL) that are shown in the image below. I've no clue how it's called exactly so I had hard time searching for the solution.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihzlJ.png

Those are textured quads, but it's same with models and other kinds of primitives. Antialiasing is helping it only a bit. I'm sorry that I have to post that, probably there were lot of questions about it but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load the texture using [**mipmap**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap), see and example below:

```
// When MAGnifying the image (no bigger mipmap available), use LINEAR filtering
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
// When MINifying the image, use a LINEAR blend of two mipmaps, each filtered LINEARLY too
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
// Generate mipmaps, by the way.
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

There are quite a lot of [tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H1ogRfMsc64) [about](http://www.g-truc.net/post-0256.html) this online.